# How to create Tiles like UI within WP8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to create Tiles like UI within our app. If I use a button with image, its showing with borders. If I create a secondary tile, then the tile is getting created on the start screen.

Is there any way to create UI which looks similar to Tiles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Hub Tile](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api) from Windows Phone Toolkit. If you want many tiles in your apps, all arranged like in the start screen of Windows Phone device, then you should use Wrap Panel as container for those Hub Tiles. You can also create Tile like UI control as demonstrated very well by @Xin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8373204/2998271)