# UI controller that mimics home screen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to create a UI controller that would look like a home screen?  Or is there one already?

I am trying to make one using a Grid controller, but I am struggling with sizing - I could not find exact sizes for tiles, margins, only for their content, and it appears that margins and tile sizes change on over-scroll.

I would like to use this to display something like a picture album.

Comment: Similar question : [How to create Tiles like UI within WP8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161354/how-to-create-tiles-like-ui-within-wp8-app)

Comment: If you're targeting WP 8.1, look at the [GridView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer for photo album is `WrapPanel`.
One of the new controls in the Silverlight Toolkit is  WrapPanel. It enables users to position child elements sequentially from left to right or top to bottom.  When elements extend beyond the panel edge, they are positioned in the next row or column.

For more Refrence how to use it go [here](http://debugmode.net/2011/12/03/how-to-work-with-wrappanel-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: Does windows phone toolkit support wp8.1?