# Windows phone 8.1 Button styling

Tags: button, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone app not silverlight just basic app.
Is there any way to make the buttons of my app look like tile. That means I want tiles for my buttons inside the pages.
I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372733/how-can-i-make-something-like-this-tiles-inside-the-app-windows-phone)

but I am getting error like "the default namespace is not defined" in the line marked when i put this code on my page.

```
*<Style x:Key="TileListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">*
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="64"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,12,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="173"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="173"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: not clear about your question. Please clarify what you need exactly.

Comment: In your defined template use image control and try it

Comment: Could you plz elaborate on this..what do I need to do exactly..

Answer (score 0):

On the link that you have provided, the BBC app are using HubTiles and attaching onClick event Handlers to make them seem as buttons.

Please use HubTile from telerik or something and you will achieve the SAME SAME result as that of BBC app